# Is there an archive for site newsletters?

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I have been following some of the [site newsletters](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/stack-exchange-site-newsletters/) and now I have time to review some of them. Is there any archive for old newsletters?

They were stored and tagged in my Gmail. While there was thousands of them there it had made a bad view for my inbox, so I deleted them, unfortunately! Now, is there any way to find them on Stack Exchange?

Comment: "do you know any trick to archive them out of our mail inbox?" depending your mail client you can export/archive emails that fulfills a criteria.

Comment: No such archive, and request to create such archive was declined.